# SQL Joining rows after using count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, union

I am trying to display a list of players from team #1 and the stats to go with them, here are the tables

table 1: players

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║ id | fname | lname | team ║
╠═══════════════════════════╣
║ 1 | Jason | McFee | 1     ║
║ 2 | John | Smith  | 1     ║
║ 3 | Jack | Doe    | 1     ║
║ 4 | Wayne | Gretzky | 2   ║
╚═══════════════════════════╝
```

---

table 2: events_goals

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║ id  g_id  a1_id  a2_id  ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1  2  3             ║
║ 2   3  1  2             ║
║ 3   2  1  NULL          ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

What I want to get is this
Name - being concat from table
Goals - COUNT all the times player id is in g_id column
Assists - COUNT (a1_id) + COUNT (a2_id) all the times playerid is in either of those columns
POINTS - sum of goals + assists

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id | name | goals | assists | points ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   J.McFee    1      2          3   ║
║ 2   J.Smith    1      2          3   ║
║ 3   J.Doe      1      1          2   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

What I have tried to do

```
>SELECT id,
>CONCAT_WS(', 'SUBSTR(fname, 1, 1), lname) name,
>FROM players 
>WHERE teamid = 1
```

This gets me a return of the names of all the players on the team with the ID of 1 with there names in proper format no problem.

I can get the count of a single player by using

```
>SELECT COUNT(g_id) FROM events_goals WHERE id = (playerid)
```

This returns the correct number of goals for player

However when I go to put it all together the stats are wrong and it only displays 1 row when i know there is supposed to be three

```
> SELECT a.id,
> CONCAT_WS(', 'SUBSTR(a.fname, 1, 1), a.lname) name,
> (COUNT(b.g_id))goals, 
> (COUNT(c.a1_id))a1, 
> (COUNT(d.a2_id))a2 
> FROM players a
> LEFT JOIN events_goals b ON a.id = b.g_id 
> LEFT JOIN events_goals c ON a.id = c.a1_id 
> LEFT JOIN events_goals d ON a.id = d.a2_id WHERE teamid = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  CONCAT_WS(', ', SUBSTR(p.fname, 1, 1), p.lname) name,
  COALESCE(eg_goals.goals, 0) goals, 
  COALESCE(eg_assists1.assists, 0) + COALESCE(eg_assists2.assists, 0) assists,
  COALESCE(eg_goals.goals, 0) + COALESCE(eg_assists1.assists, 0) + COALESCE(eg_assists2.assists, 0) points
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT g_id, COUNT(g_id) goals FROM events_goals
  GROUP BY g_id
) eg_goals ON p.id = eg_goals.g_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT a1_id, COUNT(a1_id) assists FROM events_goals
  GROUP BY a1_id
) eg_assists1 ON p.id = eg_assists1.a1_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT a2_id, COUNT(a2_id) assists FROM events_goals
  GROUP BY a2_id
) eg_assists2 ON p.id = eg_assists2.a2_id
WHERE p.team = 1
```

You should seriously reconsider redesigning your schema. Having those "events" mixed in the same table lead to horrible and very hard to maintain queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As for the schema, each row is a single event. When scoring a goal in hockey you have the goal scorer and 2 potential players contributing assists on the same event so there aren't multiple events happening on each row. Would you recommend I store goals, a1 assists and a2 assists in seperate tables?

Comment: Hmm, ok. Then leave it the way it is. Splitting it will give you worse headaches :)

Comment: Ya, thats what i figured I spent hours debating schemas for this project, the solution we came up with currently seems to be the best relational db schema. Thanks a lot for your help, I have to eventually add another table (PENALTIES) into this query but I think you gave me enough information to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) (see also [SQL GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp))

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
**SQL GROUP BY Syntax**

SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;



SELECT a.id,
CONCAT_WS(', 'SUBSTR(a.fname, 1, 1), a.lname) name,
(COUNT(b.g_id))goals, 
(COUNT(c.a1_id))a1, 
(COUNT(d.a2_id))a2 
FROM players a
LEFT JOIN events_goals b ON a.id = b.g_id 
LEFT JOIN events_goals c ON a.id = c.a1_id 
LEFT JOIN events_goals d ON a.id = d.a2_id 
WHERE teamid = 1
GROUP BY a.id,
CONCAT_WS(', 'SUBSTR(a.fname, 1, 1), a.lname)
```

Comment: The GROUP BY solved the issue of displaying only 1 row of data, however the COUNT does not seem to be displaying correctly... any ideas on why the data would be corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Using **COALESCE**

```
SELECT a.id,
        CONCAT_WS(', ', SUBSTR(a.fname, 1, 1), a.lname) name,
        (COUNT(b.g_id)) goals,  
        ((COALESCE(COUNT(c.a1_id),0)) + (COALESCE(COUNT(c.a2_id),0))) assists, 
        (COUNT(COALESCE(c.a1_id,0)) + COUNT(COALESCE(c.a2_id,0)) + COUNT(COALESCE(b.g_id,0))) points 
        FROM players a
        LEFT JOIN events_goals b ON a.id = b.g_id 
        LEFT JOIN events_goals c ON a.id = c.a1_id 
        LEFT JOIN events_goals d ON a.id = d.a2_id 
        WHERE a.teamid = 1
        GROUP BY a.id,
        CONCAT_WS(', ', SUBSTR(a.fname, 1, 1), a.lname)
```

Comment: The table is displaying exactly how I want it with name, goals, asissts, points but the data still way off.. Im not sure why

Comment: The second answer is working better, it is displaying the points correctly however the Goals and Assits data is not coming up correctly, it is double and triple what it should actually say

Comment: @JMcFee you are talking about COALESCE query

Comment: Yes sir, the COUNT(g_id) should return the number of rows that a players ID appears in the g_id column, when I do a simple query of SELECT COUNT(g_id) FROM events_goals WHERE id = (playerid) it works fine, that is why im stumped as to why it is displaying the wrong data

Comment: @JMcFee Corrected , Please check with updated changes , thanks

Comment: Whatever you just changed made the table data worse, points dont add up correctly and display correclty... I put the schema I posted above in a db on my localhost and it displays as <br> J.McFee 2g 3a 4p<br> J.Smith 1g 5a 7p <br> J.Doe 1g 0a 3p

Comment: Like I said before the format is coming perfectly, its just the data thats being a real POS right now :S, both solutions return the same data

Comment: @JMcFee dear! as i dont have ur schema or data myself, helping you on my apprehension and test!... Updated query Might work out this time

Comment: I posted all the tables and data rows in the question above, thats what im testing on before I put it into the actual system, thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: The last update you did is the closest we have gotten so far, however it is still off on the data... currently testing another way.. wll udpdate shortly